# How to pull same class elements vertically closer

Tags: html, css

As you can see the flags are too far apart vertically this happens when I shrink the browser.

[image: screen shot]

how can I fix this?

```css
.flag {
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="image" class="flag" src="flags/china-flag.pdf" href="#">
<input type="image" class="flag" src="flags/india-flag.pdf" href="#">
<input type="image" class="flag" src="flags/united-states-of-america-flag.pdf" href="#">
<input type="image" class="flag" src="flags/indonesia-flag.pdf" href="#">
<input type="image" class="flag" src="flags/pakistan-flag.pdf" href="#">
<input type="image" class="flag" src="flags/brazil-flag.pdf" href="#">
```

Comment: That is because you have margin-top and bottom set, it adds up the values when it wraps. To fix this you can just set either margin top or bottom.

Comment: @imprezzeb If I don't have this in the inputs they go above the page

Comment: Please check the answer by @Nitheesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help fellow coders!I found the problem I had other divs that were interfering with the div class=flag.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` properties. See the below example.

```css
.flag {
  width: 15px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />

<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />

<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />

<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />

<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />

<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />

<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
<input type="image" class="flag" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uN67.png" href="#" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to each element with `.flag` class. Instead, apply the margins to a container which contains all the flags. Margins on the `.flag` class should be lesser to make the flags closer.

Also, note: either of the top or bottom margin is required.